# Why I am unable to override a constant?

Tags: php, inheritance, constants

I have the following class:

```
namespace App;

class MyClass
{
    const HELLO=__CLASS__;

    public function printHello()
    {
        echo(self::HELLO);
    }
}
```

And I made another one that inherits the MyClass one:

```
namespace App;

class MyClass2 extends MyClass
{
    const HELLO=__CLASS__."2";
}
```

But why if I run:

```
$class = new \App\MyClass2();
$class->printHello();
```

I receive the following output?

```
"App\MyClass"
```

Instead of:

```
"App\MyClass22"
```

Comment: Use `static::HELLO` instead of `self::HELLO`

Comment: but why using `self` instead of `static` prints `App\MyClass`?

Comment: See the duplicate above.

Comment: Since `self` always refers to the class the method is defined in, while `static` is the actual type of the instance.